# How to get an 'axis equal' pgfplot using gnuplot, splot (implicite funtion)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, gnuplot

I get an egg for `f(x,y)=x²+y²-4=0`. I need a circle.

What have I to do?

I tested

```
set size square;
set view equal xy;
```

(and I think all I found else here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5239294/how-to-set-equal-scales-length-in-gnuplot?rq=1))

without succes.

[image]

```
% arara: pdflatex: {shell: yes}
\documentclass[margin=5mm, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}

\pgfmathsetmacro\xA{1}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot +[
%x=1cm, y=1cm, 
axis equal, 
axis equal image,
    unit vector ratio*=1 1 1,
no markers,
raw gnuplot,
thick,
%empty line = jump % not strictly necessary,
] gnuplot {
f(x,y)= x**2 +y**2-4;
set cntrparam levels discrete 0,0;
set isosample 100,100;
set size square;
set view equal xy;
set cont base;
unset surface;
splot f(x,y);
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `axis equal` is an option for the *axis*, not for an individual plot.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Ok, and what have I to do?

Comment: Add the option to the axis environment ... `\begin{axis}[axis equal]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you have the right option, but in the wrong place. `axis equal`, just like for example `width` and `height`, is an option that belongs to the `axis` environment, not to an individual plot. (Think about it, it doesn't make sense to have two plots in the same axis, where only one plot has `axis equal`.)

So you need

```
\begin{axis}[equal]
```

not

```
\addplot +[axis equal,...]
```

Comment: I am sorry, this was a thinking mistake. I do not realize, that I do not set it as axis option. Thanks at all.